# Run Python program in background - hide from taskbar

Tags: windows, python-2.7, trayicon, taskbar

I have a Python script which collects some data and sends it over to a database. Using py2exe and Inno Setup, I have been able to create an .exe for distribution and also put the program run automatically when the computer (WINDOWS) starts; **but the issue is that the command prompt window shows on the screen and on the taskbar**. I don't have anything to show in the command prompt window so **how can I make it run in the background without it being shown in the taskbar??**

Please help!!! It is also OK if it shows up only as a tray icon.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename your script file to `*.pyw` format. It able to execute your script in background mode without command prompt.
That format available from [v1.5](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.5/whatsnew/):

> The Windows configuration adds a new main program, "pythonw", and registers a new extension, ".pyw" that invokes this. This is a standard Python interpreter that does not pop up a console window; handy for pure Tkinter applications. All output to the original stdout and stderr is lost; reading from the original stdin yields EOF.

Comment: I have tried changing the extension to pyw and when I run the program from the command prompt I see no window. But when I am using py2exe to create an exe from the *.pyw file and then double clicking on the exe the command prompt window is showing. Is there any way I can stop it from appearing?

Comment: This is the py2exe code:                                                                          from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['activityWindow_4.pyw'])

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is late, but you have to force the .exe to run in background using `runhidden` in Inno Setup:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\program.exe"; Flags: postinstall runhidden
```

Instead, if you want to run a python script or batch then you can use pythonw (Winodws OS):

```
pythonw script.py/script.bat
```